# Google API does not match developer guide

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use the PHP Google API from here: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client following the Google Analytics developer guide here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide. But, they don't seem to match at all. There is no `setUseObjects` function. There is no `apiAnalyticsService` but I do see that there is a `Google_Service_Analytics` and there are a lot of other differences and it's impossible to even follow the guide even though it points to that same github repo as the client library that is supposed to be used.

Am I completely missing something here?

Comment: Had the same problem but this is my first time trying to use google api... was messing with it for a couple hours and having to rename this and that and includes man what a headache. Defiantly not the greatest of guides...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code in that page is using the old version of the library (0.6.*). You can either [download the old lib version](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/list) (not recommended) or update the code following the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/migration).